# Replacing - \" - with - " -

Tags: c#, sql, regex, postgresql, replace

I got a string wich contains a  " \ ", but i want to remove it. 
simply using

```
string.Replace(@"\", "");
```

doesnt work. 
Heres the string:

```
'Samsung Monitor 21\" '
```

Should be:

```
'Samsung Monitor 21" '
```

Ok then let me go in Detail.

Iam working with postgresql databases. My testdatabase contains some products, eg. -> Samsung Monitor 21" <-(im a bit afraid of using ' and " )
My Programm logs into the Database, reads a Table and puts it into a Datatable.
Now i want to edit the table by using the CellEdit Event. I'am constucting a string that gets run as a command by the query. Since I have no vertain Keyword, that is not allowed to be changed, I have to compare every other value of that Row to the Rows in my Database.

```
"UPDATE artikel SET warengruppe = 5 WHERE artikel_nr = '1100pplus' AND
bezeichnung = 'Samsung Monitor 21\" ' AND lieferanten_nr = 134 AND 
mengeneinheit = 'ST' AND verkaufspreis = '775.00' AND einkaufspreis 
= '465.00' AND lieferzeit = 28 AND bestand_lager = 2 AND bestand_minimum = 
10 AND jahresumsatz = '1550.00' AND vorjahresumsatz = '2325.00'"
```

Since every Value is taken out of the Datagrids Cells, it automaticly puts the Backslash infront of the -> " <-.
And I do need that to compare it in my SQLCommand.

but just giving that string like it is, it obvioulsy doesnt work, because my DataBase has

```
'Samsung Monitor 21" '
```

and not

```
'Samsung Monitor 21\" '
```

And just using "LIKE" is to much of a Workaround..

And just for the ones asking, here is my complete Method:

private void SQLDatagrid_OnCurrentCellChanged(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {

```
        DataGridColumn col1 = e.Column;
        DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;
        int row_index = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row1);
        int col_index = col1.DisplayIndex;
        int i = 0;
        string commandstring = "UPDATE artikel SET ";
        string tmpcell = dt.Rows[row_index][col_index].ToString();
        tmpcell = tmpcell.Replace(',', '.');
        bool valueisint = isInteger(tmpcell);

        commandstring += dt.Columns[col_index].ColumnName + " = ";

        if (!valueisint)
        {
            commandstring += "'";
        }
        commandstring += tmpcell;
        if (!valueisint)
        {
            commandstring += "'";
        }
        commandstring += " WHERE ";

        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dt.Columns)
        {
            string cell = dt.Rows[row_index][i].ToString();
            cell = cell.Replace(',', '.');
            bool tmp = isInteger(cell);
            if (i > 0 && i != col_index)
            {
                commandstring += " AND ";
            }
            if (i != col_index)
            {
                commandstring += dataColumn.ColumnName + " = ";
                if (!tmp)
                {
                    commandstring += "'";
                }
                commandstring += cell;
                if (!tmp)
                {
                    commandstring += "'";
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        commandstring = Regex.Replace(commandstring, @"\\", ""); // this is just trying out
        commandstring = commandstring.Replace(@"/", "");  // As is this
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandstring);
```

Comment: `string str = "'Samsung Monitor 21\\\"'";  str = str.Replace("\\", "");`

Comment: Just add one backslash to escape (`\\`): `string.Replace("\\", "");`.

Comment: I'll bet you don't have a string with `\ `. You have a string with **"**

Comment: Is it just me or does this question come up at least once a week?

Comment: I dont udnerstand why yall downvote. The string is generated by the Programm, so i cannot edit that. And ofc, the \ is escaping the ", but still, i want to remove that..

Comment: @Joschka Read the question I linked.

Comment: @Joschka where did you find this string and why do you think it contains a backslash? Did you see this in the *watch window* or *debugger tooltip* perhaps? `\" ` is *precisely* how you insert a double quote into a string.

Comment: @Joschka you'll have to provide code that actually reproduces a bug. Code that sets a string value to a variable and performs a replacement. What you typed doesn't show anything.

Comment: `but still, i want to remove that` there's **nothing** to remove. Your string does *not* contain any backslash. That's how the watch window always displayed strings, how developers always expected it to behave: the same as their code. Otherwise, tabs, newlines and non-space separators would be invisible. Check the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: @Joschka Google for `Bobby Tables`. Your string still doesn't contain any backslashes but you have a SQL injection vulnerability. If even one of those parameters contains a **single** quote, the query is invalid. Worse, if one of the values is, eg `'; DELETE FROM artikel;--` you'll lose all data. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. You should use parameterized queries instead of construnting queries by hand

Comment: @Joschka In fact, if you have a *DataTable* why are you constructing the query yourself instead of using a DbDataAdapter? A single call to [DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) will find the changed values and execute the updates

Comment: @Joschka anyway, if you insist, enter `commandstring,nq` as a watch variable, as I show in my answer. What do you see? I bet it's `UPDATE artikel SET warengruppe = 5 WHERE artikel_nr = '1100pplus' AND
bezeichnung = 'Samsung Monitor 21" ' AND lieferanten_nr = 134 AND 
mengeneinheit = 'ST' AND verkaufspreis = '775.00' AND einkaufspreis 
= '465.00' AND lieferzeit = 28 AND bestand_lager = 2 AND bestand_minimum = 
10 AND jahresumsatz = '1550.00' AND vorjahresumsatz = '2325.00'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not know about DbDataAdapter, thank you for your help

Comment: PS notice the trailing space after `"`? If the database *doesn't* have the same trailing space, the update will fail. I also noticed that you replace `,` with `.`. Are you trying to fixed a failed decimal conversion to text? You wouldn't even have a conversion if you used parameterized queries and passed numbers as numeric parameters. You *can't* cover this up either, because *thousand* separators will result in an invalid string again, eg `1.000.00`.

Comment: @Joschka I suggest you find a tutorial instead of trying code at random. This is the oldest data access technique in .NET, available since 2002. There's even a DataSet Designer that allows you to specify the columns and generate the classes. Check [this walkthrough from the documentation itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything. You don't have a string with a `\`. You have a string with a `"` **only**. The debugger and watch windows display the string in the form used by string literals in almost all languages (C#, VB.NET, Java, Javascript, PHP, Ruby), ie with a `\` in front of it.

Your string **is** `Samsung Monitor 21"`. In order to type this into code though, you'd have to write :

```
var myString = "Samsung Monitor 21\" ";
```

**NOTE**

You can force the watch window to display the string without quotes if you add the `nq` [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp) to the watch expression, eg `myString,nq`

[image: BackslashAndNQ]

This shows that the double quote is escaped in the normal watch expression, unescaped if `,nq` is added

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvotes people. Except, you'll find dozens of duplicate questions where people try to replace the non-existent backslash

Comment: I'm 100% sure you are correct - this question comes up **all** the time.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer in the last couple of years too. There were *no* such questions 2 years ago. Now it's one every week